# Passport expires soon. Can I apply for UK spouse visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I am a US citizen. I'm married to a UK citizen. I spent the last 6 months in the UK with him but my travel visa expired so I am now back in the US.

I am about to apply for a spouse visa but realized my passport (issued in 2004) expires December 2014. Do I need to renew my US passport before applying for the UK spouse visa?

Comment: You might be interested in http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's probably a good idea to renew your passport. The visa will be a full-page sticker that is affixed to your passport, and can't be moved to another passport. When your current passport expires, you would have to either:

- Apply for a transfer of your visa to your new passport (likely with a cost)
- Carry your old passport (with your visa) and your new passport whenever you travel

You're going to want to have a new passport soon anyway, since you won't be able to do things like enter another country with an expired passport. It makes sense to renew your passport now and then apply for the visa.

Comment: And wow, [at £601 that visa is expensive](https://www.gov.uk/remain-in-uk-family/overview)!

Comment: The visa will actually cost 851 pounds... from what Ive read. Thank you for the info!! :)

Comment: UK usually has a hefty cost associated with their Visas. :(

Comment: @GregHewgill Cheaper to do the immigration the other way. :)

Comment: (+1) GBP 601 is the cost to extend the visa after your initial stay (33 months if you join your spouse), the [first visa costs GBP 885](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/overview). [“Transferring” the visa costs GBP 107](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa) (actually, you can't transfer it to your new passport, you will receive a separate permit instead).